# Why can't I add text that shows my class name to jquery handle?

Tags: jquery

```
inClass = "'"+'.'+inClass+"'";      //inClass is a string
$(inClass).show();
```

Chrome console error >> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ''

I want inclass string dynamically change how can I select it with jquery? Please help

Comment: lol answer rain in one minute (:

Answer (score 1):

You do not need literal quotes in the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) itself. You only have to write:

```
$("." + inClass).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Those apostrophes are not needed, and in fact, break your query.

Instead use:

```
var inClass = "."+inClass;
$(inClass).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
inClass = '.' + inClass;
$(inClass).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this;

```
var inClass = '.'+'inClass';
$(inClass).show();
```

Bonus Usage:

html:

```
<a class="tab1">content</a>
<a class="tab2">content</a>
<a class="tab3">content</a>

<div class="tab1C">content</div>
<div class="tab2C">content</div>
<div class="tab3C">content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var take = $(this).attr('class');//takes class from clicked element

   $('div').hide();//hides all content
   $('.'+ take + 'C').show();//matches clicked elements id with div container like .tab2C
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be more appropriate:
`$('.' + inClass).show();`